# Compound interest

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Project3{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);

double rate = 0.05;
double annually, monthly, daily;
double balance;
int year = 10 ;

System.out.println("Enter the amount you will like to deposit or type exit to end.");
int deposit = key.nextInt();

annually = deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/1),year); 
monthly = deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/12),year); 
daily = deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/365),year);

while (deposit)
{

}




System.out.println(annually);
System.out.println(monthly);
System.out.println(daily);
}
}
```

This is what I currently have. What I am trying to accomplish is to make a loop to add the first outcome with the next one. Also make one formula instead of having three to find the annually, monthly and daily.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'make a loop to add the first outcome with the next one'

Comment: "Using a loop that adds in the interest for each time period, that is, do not use some sort of algebraic formula. Your program should have an outer loop that allows the user to repeat this calculation for a new balance and interest rate. The calculation is repeated until the user asks to end the program."

Comment: Well, if you're trying to add a value from the first iteration of your loop, then why not store it in a new variable? You are right to store each formula in its own variable, except I'd just put it all on one line. Side note: if this is homework, consider asking your teacher for help. It's very unethical to go on a QA site to have someone write out your homework for you.

Comment: Please give a concrete example of your desired output. It looks to me like you've solved the problem in a single line using `Math.pow()`.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, asking someone to write out your homework is really unethical, and not helpful for you in the long run. If you don't care about the long run, consider taking a different class. In a career scenario, you're expected to write code on your own.

Secondly, to actually answer your question, here are some tips:

It seems like you want to gather a value (deposit) from the user, and then calculate the Compound Interest for said value. Your program also needs to not exit until the user says to exit. i.e. they want to calculate the CI for a set of numbers.

First step is to check the value from the user. If it is a number, then do calculations on it. If it is a String, then check if it is "exit". In Java, this amounts to writing out an if-statement, and making use of the very helpful "instanceof" keyword. If you haven't learned about that, give [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) a read, or ask your teacher.

For the calculations part, you simply do calculations on the user's input while the input is not a string set to "exit".

Finally, print out your calculations.

That's it. Your code already has the calculation formulas down, so you just need to code the logic for handling user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much money you want to deposit?");
        int principle = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("what is the rate you want?");
        float rate = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("After how many years, you want to see your money?");
        int year = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many compounds in a year?");
        int partialTime = sc.nextInt();
        double b = year * partialTime;
        double a = 1 + (rate/(partialTime*100));
        double x = principle * (Math.pow(a,b));
        System.out.println("Your interest in given time would be " + x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score -2):

A couple of suggestions - since you want to check user input against both `String` and `int` types, you could define a `String` type variable to hold the user input, and then do a `try`/`catch` to parse it as an `Integer`, if it's not an `Integer` check if the input equals `"exit"` (using the `String.equals()` method).

```
import java.util.*;
public class Project3{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);

        double rate = 0.05;
        double annually = 0, monthly = 0, daily = 0;
        double balance;
        int year = 10, deposit = 0 ;
        String userinput = "";

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the amount you will like to deposit or type exit to end.");
                userinput = key.nextLine();
                deposit = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                if (!userinput.equals("exit")){
                    System.out.println("Didn't recognize that input, please try again...");
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!userinput.equals("exit"));

        annually += deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/1),year); 
        monthly += deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/12),year); 
        daily += deposit * Math.pow((1 + rate/365),year);

        System.out.println(annually);
        System.out.println(monthly);
        System.out.println(daily);
    }
}
```

Depending on how you want the output, you can easily adjust the scope of the loop to display the amounts after each valid `deposit` input, or just once at the end, after the user enters `"exit"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 for writing out someone's homework for them. The idea of teaching to program is not to program for the learner, but rather help them think about how solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Showing the learner the missing concepts I believe helps them solve their problem. Thanks for the -1 and your explanation.

Comment: But writing the code for them isn't showing them the missing concepts, it is simply showing them the easy way to the solution.

Comment: You can explain - even show - the concepts without giving working code away. I completely agree with @AndrewQuebe. -1.